# FFMpeg cant concatenate videos: Input link in31:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am using fluent-ffmpeg for NodeJS to combine many (50) videos. The command fluent-ffmpeg generates is:

```
ffmpeg -i ./temp/1426738868618B778176A-254A-47E5-80D4-AF9E2DB836C6.mp4 -i 
./temp/14267388686185827E1A1-20CC-41A7-B121-4BE088580062.mp4 -i 
./temp/142673886861811F5BEB8-6567-4771-9F73-E13D47CE6773.mp4 -i
./temp/1426738868618C72B0345-739B-4243-B739-3BEF718EDE35.mp4 -i
./temp/1426738868618F37E694A-7433-4FB5-A977-0CF28913EDF8.mp4 -i
...
./temp/142673886861869535AA6-7A08-4447-9747-A40A28C4D57C.mp4 -i
./temp/1426738868618AAD398BC-3259-4087-9535-26D73EA5209F.mp4 -i
./temp/1426738868618193CF9E5-B0FB-4B60-B273-22614C376185.mp4 -i
./temp/142673886861875ABFC64-D0BA-429F-A53E-2088F90DD6E4.mp4 
-i./temp/142673886861841290364-42E0-4159-9A75-70528B8D471E.mp4 
-y -filter_complex concat=n=50:v=1:a=1 -r 29.97 -vcodec libx264 -s 568x320 -flags +loop 
-b 400k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -subq 4 
-partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 
-level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 
-i_qfactor 0.71 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 80k -ar 48000 -ac 2 
-strict experimental -f mp4 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 ./temp/1426738868618.mp4
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x7faba20366a0] Input link in31:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (360x480, SAR 0:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x7faba20366a0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
```

I researched it and I have to do something like `"setsar=1"` but when I add that into `filter_complex` I get the exact same error.

edit: here is the full output for the command http://pastebin.com/Sk2y3WQr

Comment: Please show the **complete** console output; not just a segment.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard sure, it wouldnt fit in my question so here http://pastebin.com/Sk2y3WQr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Frame sizes

From the [concat filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

> All corresponding streams must have the same parameters in all
>   segments; the filtering system will automatically select a common
>   pixel format for video streams, and a common sample format, sample
>   rate and channel layout for audio streams, **but other settings, such
>   as resolution, must be converted explicitly by the user**.
>
> Different frame rates are acceptable but will result in variable frame
>   rate at output; be sure to configure the output file to handle it.

Your inputs vary in frame size, so therefore you must use the [scale filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to make a common frame size.

## Timestamps

Also from the same docs:

> For this filter to work correctly, all segments must start at
>   timestamp 0.

Use the [setpts filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) to do this.

## Example

A partial filtering example may look like this:

```
[0:v]scale=360x480,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[1:v]scale=360x480,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
…
[49:v]scale=360x480,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v49];
[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]…[v49][49:a]concat=n=50:v=1:a=1
```

## Use the presets

Do yourself a favor and use the encoding presets. There is no reason to declare so many options. The presets will deal with them. That's what they are for.

You can remove:

```
-flags +loop -bt 256k -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -subq 4 
-partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 
-level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 
-i_qfactor 0.71
```

And replace these options with `-preset faster` or whatever preset you prefer. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.